# Why does the styling for lightning-input-field change when variant="label-hidden"?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to replace the field label for a lightning-input-field element.

```
<label class="slds-form-element__label">Label Here</label>
<lightning-input-field class="application-field" id="Discipline_Disclosure__c" field-name="Discipline_Disclosure__c" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input-field>
```

When I apply the variant "label-hidden", however, the styling of the element is changed and is now not horizontally aligned with the elements above and below it, as seen below.

[image]

Pictured are two lightning-input-field elements with the variant "label-hidden" and one regular lightning-input-field element.

Is there a reason this is happening? And, how can I get the "label-hidden" elements to line up with their base variant counterparts?

Answer (score 0):

That's because Original Field Name which is hidden is still using the space on the layout and which is why input text box came to next line.